# localStorage.setItem doesn't work with <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

I got a JS function that reads from specific field of my dict and set the read values on new page to the tags they are related to.

```
const good_render = id => {
  localStorage.setItem("name", (goods[id].name));
  localStorage.setItem("price", (goods[id].price));
  localStorage.setItem("img", (goods[id].img))};
```

I apply these values this way:

```
 <script>
        document.getElementById("name").textContent = name = localStorage.getItem("name");
        document.getElementById("price").textContent = price = localStorage.getItem("price");
        document.getElementById("img").src = img = localStorage.getItem("img")
 </script>
```

It works perfectly fine with .textContend, however with .src it doesn't. What might be the problem?
=Update=
Briefly, a button must be pressed so to travel to a product page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main_2_buttons.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="../good_page/good_page.html" class="button-34" id="good1">good 1</a>
    <a href="../good_page/good_page.html" class="button-34" id="good2">good 2</a>

    <script src="main_2_buttons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The product page itself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider\itc-slider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="good_page.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1 class="header1" id = "name"></h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="itc-slider" data-slider="itc-slider">
        <div class="itc-slider-wrapper">
          <div class="itc-slider-items">
            <div class="itc-slider-item">
                <img src = "slider\examples\images\1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="itc-slider-item">
                <img src = "slider\examples\images\2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="itc-slider-item">
                <img src = "slider\examples\images\3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="itc-slider-item" id ="img">
                <img src = "slider\examples\images\4.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="itc-slider-btn itc-slider-btn-prev"</button>
        <button class="itc-slider-btn itc-slider-btn-next"</button>
      </div>
</div>
<div> <!--class="nl l1n"-->>
    <div class="header1" id = "price"></div>
    <div>
        <button class="button-3" role="button" id="cart">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="slider\itc-slider.js" defer></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("name").textContent = name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    document.getElementById("price").textContent = price = localStorage.getItem("price");
    document.getElementById("img").src = img = localStorage.getItem("img")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the executed JS

```
var goods = {                 
    "good1" : {               
        "name" : "good1",
        "price": 100,
        "img"  : "https://static.winestreet.ru/off-line/goods_file/46001/file_S.jpg",
        "in_store": 1,
    },

    "good2" : {
        "name" : "good2",
        "price": 50,
        "img"  : "https://pitersmoke.ru/wa-data/public/shop/products/90/15/11590/images/18550/18550.970.jpg",
        "in_store": 1,
    }
};

document.onclick = event => { 
    if (event.target.id == 'good1') {
        good_render(event.target.id);
    }

    if (event.target.id == 'good2') {
        good_render(event.target.id);
    }
};

const good_render = id => {
    localStorage.setItem("name", (goods[id].name));
    localStorage.setItem("price", (goods[id].price));
    const imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(goods[id].img);
    localStorage.setItem("img", imgURL);  
};
```

Comment: Is it completely not working or do you just not see the image in the UI (ie, how are you testing that "it doesn't work" - there's multiple levels of "not working").  Perhaps `goods[id].img` is not as expected / valid.

Comment: The value is added to the local storage, however it is not seen in the UI.

Comment: What do you see in your browser's devtools' local-storage explorer?

Comment: Sounds like it's not a correct value for img src attribute

Comment: In local storage I see img key and value

Comment: This should actually work, however your script `slider\itc-slider.js` might be interferring. I couldn't find the concrete library by googling, so it's still just a guess. So maybe you can try to remove that script temporarily and see whether it's working without it. If it's due to the library, you might have to find an option within the library to set the image.

Comment: @LevGor ... `const imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(goods[id].img);` is not needed at all. Just rename the `img` key of your `good` model to e.g. `imgSrc` (**for exactly naming its purpose**) and put it into the local storage like the other model values e.g. ... `localStorage.setItem("imgSrc", (goods[id].imgSrc));`. Retrieving the value again from the storage and assigning it to the **correct image element** (**notice the selector**) then is likewise as simple e.g. ... `document.querySelector("#img > img").src = imgSrc = localStorage.getItem("imgSrc");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("img")` returns `div` element as per your HTML in question, so either set `id` to your `img` tag instead of `div` or do:

```
var myDivEle = document.getElementById("img"); //its a <div> not <img />
myDivEle.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = localStorage.getItem("img");
```